# Can't get http to work in php

Tags: php, http, amazon-ec2, pecl

I keep getting this error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so: undefined symbol: php_persistent_handle_abandon in Unknown on line 0

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpResponse' not found in /var/www/api/init.php on line 4

I've reinstalled http through pecl a few times, even tried installing it from the tar.gz. I'm running an EC2 instance.

I HAVE put extension=http.so in my php.ini.

Comment: How did you install php? I often see this with multiple php installs with inconsistent module locations.

Comment: I installed php using yum. I have php 5.3. I just tried downgrading to pecl http 1.6.7, which worked, but now I can't find http.so

Comment: Did you install pecl via yum as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pecl\_http faild to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077976/pecl-http-faild-to-load)

Answer (score 11):

You probably got version 2 of pecl_http, and it has some new requirements. See the [installation instructions](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http). For me these lines worked:

```
extension=raphf.so
extension=propro.so
extension=http.so
```

*Edit:* Order matters, so first try the same order as I used.

I also made sure http.so is loaded after json.so and the other prerequisites.

Comment: Make sure that this is the exact order when you list in php.ini

Answer (score 5):

I installed pecl_http successfully with following steps on Debian

1. execute

   `sudo pecl install raphf propro pecl_http`
2. create /etc/php5/mods-available/zhttp.ini

   `extension=raphf.so
   extension=propro.so
   extension=http.so`
3. execute

   `sudo php5enmod zhttp`
4. restart your web server

Comment: Running `php -r 'http_post_data();'` still gives me `Call to undefined function http_post_data()`

Answer (score 2):

As mine was using /etc/php/conf.d/ for the additional .ini files
I just prefixed them with numbers

```
mv raphf.ini 1raphf.ini
mv propro.ini 2propro.ini
mv http.ini 3http.ini


# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/conf.d/1raphf.ini,
/etc/php/conf.d/2propro.ini,
/etc/php/conf.d/3http.ini,
/etc/php/conf.d/imagick.ini
```

Comment: actually http.ini should really load at the very end of all other extensions. I renamed it to zzzhttp.ini instead and it solved another issue I had.

Comment: oh man!, thanks a lot. This worked. Wasted hours and hours.. sigh

Answer (score -1):

This solution have worked for me on php7.2-fpm

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "xxxx";
$db_pass = "xxxx";
$connect = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
$db_name = "xxxx";

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connect, $db_name);

// Empty table
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE xtabletotruncatex";
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```