# Unable to use pecl_http2.5.1 even though it has installed

Tags: php, apache, http, pear, pecl

I am unable to make use of pecl_http2.5.1 even though it appears in my pecl list but not in phpinfo(), it has been enabled in php.ini, i get the following error message in the browser:

http\Client\Request' not found

I have enabled it using php5enmod http and still nothing seems to happen  in phpinfo(),i have copied the http.so file to the mods-avilable folder as well.

Please help?

Comment: You likely also need to restart your web server (assuming you're using that as opposed to the CLI to test) for any changes to php.ini (which loading a module makes) to take effect.

Comment: i have done this numerous time also

Comment: and no luck , the module http.so is in the mods-available folder where it should be.

Comment: The `http.so` binary shouldn't be in mods-available. It should be in the default location for PHP modules. This sounds like you're on a Debian system, so that should be /etc/php5/{build-date}/http.so.  Did you install it via pecl on the command line, or via apt-get?

Comment: Here you go - this seems to address what you're probably seeing (if it is the same as what I saw) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079679/cant-get-http-to-work-in-php

Comment: yes i did install it via pecl command apt-get im on a ubuntu 15.04. sorry i added the http.ini file in mods available folder.

Comment: All 3 of the dependent extensions mentioned in that other question should be available in Ubuntu repos like `php5-propro, php5-raphf, php5-pecl-http`.  all installable directly via apt-get.

Comment: yes i have all the 3 dependencies installed as well, when i run php-m and pecl list the http extension has loaded successfully.

Comment: ok i install the packages via php5-propro now im getting this now: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0. Shall i delete the old http.so file?

Comment: Now that sounds like you don't have the json extension loaded. Check mods-available for json.ini and php5enmod it. Install if not present, but as far as I know, I expect it should be bundled by default.

Comment: yes it exists in that directory and i seem to be getting that error. it is bundled by default you are right

Comment: json is in the list when i do php-m

Comment: to prove it : Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I'm sorry to say I'm sort of out of ideas. I don't use pecl HTTP because Guzzle is more full-featured and far less hassle to get running http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: thanks for your time

Comment: My last recommendation would be to verify that the json extension is enabled both in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and /etc/php5/cli/conf.d because when you do `php -m` you'll get output for the CLI, which may have read a different php.ini than Apache to begin with.

Comment: its enabled in both cli and apache2

Comment: im getting a different message now: /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: undefined symbol: php_persistent_handle_resource_factory_init, everything is defined in a correct order.

Comment: I think that's raphf.

Comment: yes ive fixed that now as well, but no http enabled in phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, you've also [installed and enabled all dependencies](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http#PHP.extensions:).